# Adding a break to a bubble sort in case the array is already sorted

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, sorting

I currently have a (somewhat messy) bubble sort of an object array called "sorted", the code is as follows

```
object storage = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Length; i++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < sorted.Length - 1; c++)
    {
        if (sorted[c].ToString().CompareTo(sorted[c + 1].ToString()) > 0)
        {
            storage = sorted[c + 1];
            sorted[c + 1] = sorted[c];
            sorted[c] = storage;
        }
    }
    return sorted;
```

Problem is that this function always loops through the array , no matter what. Hypothetically speaking the "sorted" array could be a large array and just so happen to be sorted already, in which case the function would still scan the array and work for some time, which I want to prevent.
So the question is, how do I stop the loop properly in case the array is sorted already?

Comment: There is no inbuilt function to check whether array is sorted or not. in each case you need to visit each element of array. Best time complexity for sorted array is O(n).

Comment: Does insertion sort work for you? It has O(n) time complexity for already sorted arrays.

Comment: There is a more general optimization, you can limit the inner loop to the position where the last iteration did a swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bubble sort bubbles the largest (smallest) element of an array towards the end of an array. This is what your inner loop does.

First of all you can take advantage of the knowledge that after n iterations, the last n elements are sorted already, which means that your inner loop doesn't need to check the last n elements in the (n+1)th iteration.

Secondly, if the inner loop doesn't change anything, the elements must be in sequence already, which is a good point for a break of the outer loop.

Since you're doing this as a practising exercise, I'll leave the coding up to you :-)

Comment: Better, but still not the 'optimal' bubble sort. As contradictory as that is.

Comment: Yes your comment regarding the more optimal optimisation will make it even better. granted. It is a generalisation of my second point.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `OrderBy` instead of sorting it yourself?

```
sorted = sorted.OrderBy(s=> s).ToArray();
```

If you insist to use the bubble sort, you can do this:

```
bool changed;
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Length; i++)
{
    changed = false;
    for (int c = 0; c < sorted.Length - 1; c++)
    {
        if (sorted[c].ToString().CompareTo(sorted[c + 1].ToString()) > 0)
        {
            changed = true;
            storage = sorted[c + 1];
            sorted[c + 1] = sorted[c];
            sorted[c] = storage;
        }
        if(!changed) break;
    }
```

I'm setting changed to false each time in the first loop. If there was no changes to the end, then the array is already sorted.

Comment: Simply practicing different stuff right now, bubble sort being one of them :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
object storage = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Length; i++)
{
    bool swapped = false;
    for (int c = 0; c < sorted.Length - 1; c++)
    {
        if (sorted[c].ToString().CompareTo(sorted[c + 1].ToString()) > 0)
        {
            storage = sorted[c + 1];
            sorted[c + 1] = sorted[c];
            sorted[c] = storage;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
    if (!swapped)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If it gets through a pass without swapping then the array is ordered so it will `break`.